# Filtering JSON Response in C#

Tags: c#, json, filter, filtering, where-clause

My Json data is like that.. I want to take monthlyAnnualCostRate by dueNum.
So I want to say:
What is the monthlyAnnualCostRate value of the data whose dueNum value is x?

For example;
User giving info: dueNum=46 | Ok, I will calculate the monthlyAnnualCostRate by counting 1.8800

```
{
               "dueNum": 45,
               "installmentAmount": 28.89,
               "monthlyInterestRate": 1,
               "capitalAmount": 1000,
               "totalInstallmentAmount": 1300.03,
               "advancePaymentAmount": 0,
               "expenseAmount": 100,
               "annualCostRate": 22.7034,
               "monthlyContractRate": 1,
         "monthlyAnnualCostRate": 1.8920,
               "interestAmount": 250.01,
               "fundAmount": 37.52,
               "taxAmount": 12.5
            },
                  {
               "dueNum": 46,
               "installmentAmount": 28.42,
               "monthlyInterestRate": 1,
               "capitalAmount": 1000,
               "totalInstallmentAmount": 1307.03,
               "advancePaymentAmount": 0,
               "expenseAmount": 100,
               "annualCostRate": 22.5604,
               "monthlyContractRate": 1,
         "monthlyAnnualCostRate": 1.8800,
               "interestAmount": 255.83,
               "fundAmount": 38.39,
               "taxAmount": 12.81
            },
                  {
               "dueNum": 47,
               "installmentAmount": 27.96,
               "monthlyInterestRate": 1,
               "capitalAmount": 1000,
               "totalInstallmentAmount": 1314.22,
               "advancePaymentAmount": 0,
               "expenseAmount": 100,
               "annualCostRate": 22.4208,
               "monthlyContractRate": 1,
         "monthlyAnnualCostRate": 1.8684,
               "interestAmount": 261.85,
               "fundAmount": 39.27,
               "taxAmount": 13.1
            },
```

And It's my codes. I tried this process but i take error.
Error:
"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.'
"

My Codes:

```
string uri = "https://apis.garantibbva.com.tr:443/loans/v1/paymentPlan";
            var client = new RestClient(uri);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("apikey", "l7xx8af86c14ea7e44e0ab3fbfcc6137ae09");
            request.AddQueryParameter("loanType", "1");
            request.AddQueryParameter("campaignCode", "BankSearch");
            request.AddQueryParameter("loanAmount", "10000");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            
            var dueNum = 46;
            double monthlyAnnualCostRate = JArray.Parse(response.Content)
                .Where(p => (int)p["dueNum"]==dueNum)
                .Select(p => (double)p["monthlyAnnualCostRate"])
                .FirstOrDefault();

            _logger.LogInformation("Garanti Bankası Response: {monthlyAnnualCostRate}", monthlyAnnualCostRate);
            _logger.LogInformation("Garanti Bankası geçti");
```

JSON Starting:

```
{
         "data": {"list":    [
                  {
               "dueNum": 3,
               "installmentAmount": 341.37,
               "monthlyInterestRate": 1,
               "capitalAmount": 1000,
               "totalInstallmentAmount": 1024.11,
               "advancePaymentAmount": 0,
               "expenseAmount": 100,
               "annualCostRate": 118.9411,
               "monthlyContractRate": 1,
         "monthlyAnnualCostRate": 9.9118,
               "interestAmount": 20.08,
               "fundAmount": 3.02,
               "taxAmount": 1.01
            },
                  {
               "dueNum": 4,
               "installmentAmount": 257.54,
               "monthlyInterestRate": 1,
               "capitalAmount": 1000,
               "totalInstallmentAmount": 1030.18,
               "advancePaymentAmount": 0,
               "expenseAmount": 100,
               "annualCostRate": 92.9855,
               "monthlyContractRate": 1,
         "monthlyAnnualCostRate": 7.7488,
               "interestAmount": 25.15,
               "fundAmount": 3.77,
               "taxAmount": 1.26
            },
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: You have to post json data as a text, not as a picture.

Comment: The above is not valid JSON. An array in JSON begins and ends with `[]` and does not have a trailing comma. Judging by what you can get if you run the code, the JSON looks like it begins `{"data": {"list":[{"dueNum"...` which makes more sense

Comment: @Charlieface it's already begins and ends with `[]`. I put just a part of JSON response.

Comment: Please give a [mcve], with stress on "reproducible", it has to show your issue properly. You can't expect us to diagnose incorrect JSON handling without giving us the full JSON

Comment: @Charlieface i edited main question now, added JSON starting things

Comment: @Charlieface
`double monthlyAnnualCostRate = JObject.Parse(json)["data"]["list"].Where(p => (int)p["dueNum"] == dueNum).Select(p => (double)p["monthlyAnnualCostRate"]).FirstOrDefault();`
It worked thanks :) Please add this comment as an answer. I will select as true answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have a JSON *object* which contains a `data` property, which contains a `list` property` which contains the array. The array is not the root.

So you need this

```cs
double monthlyAnnualCostRate = JObject.Parse(json)["data"]["list"]
    .Where(p => (int)p["dueNum"] == dueNum)
    .Select(p => (double)p["monthlyAnnualCostRate"])
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Creating a proper object model (using Visual Studio's "Paste JSON as Classes") and then deserializing directly to that would make things a lot easier.

Comment: No I copied the OP's code and modified it, I even put that into a now deleted comment

Comment: @Charlieface You know as well as me it doesn't matter, what text is in square brackets, the most important what is after brackets.   And  you have copied it from me.

Comment: @Serge OP has the following *in their post*: `double monthlyAnnualCostRate = JArray.Parse(response.Content).Where(p => (int)p["dueNum"]==dueNum).Select(p => (double)p["monthlyAnnualCostRate"]).FirstOrDefault();` that is what I copied

Comment: @Serge So do you still think I copied your answer? You can see for yourself OP had that code

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```cs
var dueNum = 46;

decimal monthlyAnnualCostRate = ((JArray) JObject.Parse(json)["data"]["list"])
       .Where(p => (int)p["dueNum"] == dueNum)
       .Select(p => (double)p["monthlyAnnualCostRate"])
       .FirstOrDefault(); //1.88
```

Comment: ```Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.' ```

I take this error.

I will add my codes.

Comment: I edited now again. You can see my codes and error in main question

Comment: @OğuzhanDurmaz What you have posted is not valid json at all. Pls post the real json .

Comment: @OğuzhanDurmaz I updated my answer according to your new json